# NServiceBus.Azure and EF SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, nservicebus

I have configured Entity Framework to use SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. Now my NServiceBus handlers fail with the following error:

> NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver: Failed to process
>   message System.InvalidOperationException: The configured execution
>   strategy 'SqlAzureExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated
>   transactions

As I understand, NServiceBus by default wraps my handler code in a transaction. If it is true, how can I disable it? Or is the only way to resolve this to give up using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Configure.Transactions.Advanced(s =>
{
    s.DisableDistributedTransactions(); // disables transaction on receive
    s.DoNotWrapHandlersExecutionInATransactionScope(); // disables transactions on business logic
});

Comment: I assume the NServiceBus 5.0 analog to this is configuration.Transactions().DisableDistributedTransactions(); but it doesn't prevent this exception in my WorkerRole.